# How do I allocate variable damage to multi-wound models?

Tags: warhammer-40k

Let's say my grav cannons (D3 damage) shoot at some crisis suits (3 wounds each) and the suits fail 3 saves. I roll damage and get a one, a two and a three. Should I have rolled the dice in order? Or can I roll them together and allocate? Or do I roll them together and the other player allocates?

To see how different this could be:

- If I allocate, I'll apply the three first, then the one and the two, killing two models
- If the target player allocates, he'll apply the two, then the three, killing one model. The one then gets applied to a fresh model, leaving it with two wounds.
- Or, if applied in order, I might have rolled the one first, then the three, then the two. That would kill one model and leave another with one wound remaining.

Comment: @Nij, hmm, that's more about making saves and single-wound models. The answer does actually work out to be the same, but I wanted to get an explicit answer for variable damage and multi-wound models.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With variable damage against multi-wound models (or models with a Feel No Pain equiv.) you need to roll the damage rolls one at a time. The damage is not rolled and then assigned. The only choice you would have is if you had a weapon whose profile changed based on hit/wound roll (for example d6 instead of d3 on a 6 to wound). In this case you would make two groups of wound pools, and the firing player could decide which should be applied first, the defending player would then make the saves against these. If the defending models had differing saves (or some had FNP) the saves and damage rolls would need to be made individually.

The important thing to remember is that technically group rolling is a shortcut. Each weapon is intended to be fired individually. This is of course tedious, so where possible, when it doesn't actually matter, we group rolls together.

Comment: OK, that makes sense. Though, to clarify, those three failed saves could all come from one weapon (a Grav Cannon is Heavy 4). Would it be more correct to say that each *shot* must be fired individually?

Comment: If you read the Fast Dice Rolling sidebar in the core rules primer, the rules are designed that you make one hit at a time, but there are situations where you can save time by making multiple rolls at once. With a Grav Cannon, I'd certainly roll the 4 hit/wound rolls at the same time. The main time you'd need to fire each shot individually is if you were shooting at a unit with mixed toughness, since the number needed to wound could change as models die.